# how to check server reachability using curl command?

Tags: json, shell, curl

I am using curl command to hit the server. i am getting header body in response.if status=200 server is up.how do i write shell script to check whether my server is down and trigger the mail?

Command:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "X-Auth-Token: token which is generated after login " -d "{
  \"authSource\": \"APKIRAI\",
  \"email\": \"username\",
  \"password\": \"password(xxx)\"}" "api url(login)"
```

Response:

```
{"status":1,"message":"All is well","body":{"token":"anandkhot.actovoice@gmail.com:1:1467298960095:405a3dcd524cd673ebc4fd59a31fbabc","expires":1467298960095}}
```

Comment: Hi ANAND, This requires you learn shell scripting. Here is not the good place.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that might be a starting point... It would poll your site every 10 seconds, add in your curl command.
Put it in a file called poll.sh and run it with `sh poll.sh`

```
while True
do
    resp=$(curl )
    if [ -z $resp ]
    then
        echo "Failed"
        echo $resp
    else
        echo "OK"
    fi
    sleep 10
done
```